Flying over the Grand Canyon SFAR - what altitude should you fly if you encounter clouds at appropriate altitude?
I was recently flying over the Grand Canyon on our way to St. George using the SFAR routes assigned.  We were flying with flight following and was assigned the appropriate altitude I had previously verified with the chart.  Shortly after entering the corridor, we encountered clouds.  I assumed since we had flight following, we were safe, but since I'm not instrument rated, I didn't feel it was appropriate VFR.  What altitude could we have flown at to be within the SFAR and/or should we have asked the controller for a different altitude?  The issue was that we were already 11,500 in a C-172, so climbing to 13,500 probably wasn't feasible.  Any suggestions?

I assumed since we had flight following, we were safe - NO. Flight following is NOT traffic separation. It is traffic advisories and safety alerts. You only get separation when you're in B/C/TRSA airspace, and even in C/TRSA you aren't separated from ALL traffic—only certain traffic.

I have flown that route and encountered this same situation. You have two options.
Climbing to 13,500

if your aircraft is capable
if you are confident of your physiological response to hypoxia at that level
if you are sure that you can descend back below 12.5 within 30 minutes (91.211) assuming that you are not oxygen equipped,
if your will have VFR appropriate cloud clearance 1000' above tops of clouds

Your other choice is a 180 course reversal to remain clear of clouds and exit the corridor.
As @randomhead points out, you could declare an emergency, but this would likely be received with some tough questions from the FSDO because this would appear to be an emergency of your own making where you clearly had a non-emergency "out" with a 180.

Having flight following in no way relieves you of your 91.155 cloud distance requirements. You are expected to comply with 91.155 at all times. If a published procedure or ATC instruction would cause you to violate 91.155 you are expected to speak up and request alternate instructions from ATC.
A VFR aircraft in IMC is an honest-to-goodness emergency, even if you were instrument rated which you aren't. As such you can invoke 91.3(b) PIC authority and do what you need to do in order to meet the emergency, that is, get out of the clouds.
You should have communicated what was happening to ATC and done something to get out of IMC—a climb, a descent, a 180º turn. Something.
